# Do 'while' loops work with try and except?

Tags: python

So I have a script that isn't quite working yet but I am hoping to get it to a point where it keeps trying to connect to a server until it finally succeeds (using the paramiko library). In simplistic terms, this is what my code is like:

```
canConnect = False
while canConnect == False:
    try:
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ps')
        if stdout.read():
            canConnect = True
        else:
            # cannot connect
            time.sleep(20)
    except:
        # cannot connect
        time.sleep(20)
```

Now... this would be quite basic for a simple if statement but gets more complicated because I need to use "try" and "except". If the code can connect successfully (using "ps" as a random command that returns content and will prove the server is connectable), I assume it passes into the if condition that then sets canConnect to True and stops the loop. If it cannot connect, I think Paramiko will throw an exception (I put the "else" command there just in case), but once it hits the "except", it should wait for 20 seconds and then I assume the while statement will take the code back to the beginning and start again? What I have witnessed so far is that *some* kind of loop is happening, but it doesn't actually appear to be attempting to connect to the server.

Also, an unrelated question, documentation is scarce but I assume Paramiko /has/ to take 3 arguments like that to perform an exec_command (regardless of variables assigned, they will take standard output In, Out, Err in that order?)? I also assume it is uncommon to assign multiple comma-delimited variables to something like that, besides lists or method calls?

Comment: Does this code work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Your problem is probably because your `except:` catches *anything* that may go wrong; if anything goes wrong with the `ssh.exec_command` line unrelated to the networking, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: `break`, `finally`, and you will have a much cleaner code.

Comment: Also you should use `while not canConnect:` instead of `while canConnect == False:`, its more pythonic

Comment: Congratulations, you just learned one _very important_ lesson: _never_ use a bare except clause (unless you re-raise the very same exception, and even then...)

Comment: As an update here, looks like the root of my problem was not related to the loop logic at all. It looks like after a reboot, the paramiko SSH connection is terminated and I must re-attempt to open it first post-reboot, otherwise all attempted queries will result in the SSHException being returned. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of `except:` may be masking the real problem, as it catches all exceptions, and disregards them. That would explain the `some kind of loop is happening, but it doesn't actually appear to be attempting to connect to the server` behavior. consider changing that to something like:

```
except (paramiko.SSHException, socket.error)
```

Comment: I've tried that out and it is still catching and constantly hitting the except clause in a loop whenever the actual server is not connectable. I am assuming your suggestion makes it so that the program only hits the except when it throws a SSHException exception or a socket.error? I don't suppose you know of a way to print out the actual exception (just in case it isn't sshexception or socket.error?) Although... even if it was a different error, I'm not sure why it fails to satisfy the requirements of the first if statement that stops the loop.

Comment: add this: `import traceback` and than `traceback.print_exc()` in the except block. or just dont catch it and see the stack trace output.

Comment: Yeah.. looks like it does raise "paramiko.SSHException: SSH session not active". I guess I'll keep trying to figure out why this is happening when the server is up. Else, guess I might just re-imagine a different method to test whether or not the server is connectable after a reboot. Thanks.